# Convert Cpp code snippet to VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net

Battling on in my attempts to import a wireless profile using WLANSetProfile, the Microsoft 6.1 SDK example (WLSample.exe) works quite happily with my XML profile.

Could a kind soul please show me how to convert these code snippets to VB.NET and advise what they do? Do I need them in VB.Net to achieve the correct outcome?

```
hr=CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument60,
                    NULL,
                    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                    IID_IXMLDOMDocument2,
                    (void**)&pXmlDoc
                    );

hr=pXmlDoc->load((CComVariant)argv[2], &vbSuccess);

hr=pXmlDoc->get_xml(&bstrXml);
```

From what I can tell, as this is a console program, it needs to create a blob of memory in to which it loads the specified XML file (as a string).

What I really need to know is the last one - &bstrXml. What does that mean? On the surface, it appears to convert an XML file... to... an XML file! Is it a byte array? What is the equivalent VB.NET syntax?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just reads the *entire* content of an XML file into a string.  Hard to believe that's useful and you really ought to be using the System.Xml namespace or the XDocument class.  But this is a COM object so is just as easily usable from a VB.NET program.

Project + Add Reference, select the COM tab and select "Microsoft XML, v6.0".  And use it like:

```
    Dim path = "c:\temp\test.xml"              // Just one I tested on my machine
    Dim document = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60()
    document.load(path)
    Dim content = document.xml
    Debug.Write(content)
```

Doesn't look that much like the C++ code, but VB.NET supports COM a lot better.  It knows about properties and takes care of error checking automatically.